# How to get GridView.ShowHeaderWhenEmpty Property to display headers

Tags: c#, header, aspxgridview, is-empty, asp.net-4.6

I am using `.NET Framework 4.6.1` in my Asp.Net application and trying to apply the  `GridView.ShowHeaderWhenEmpty` property to my gridview to display the headers on page load (before the data table has data fill in the rows and is empty). When I load this page, there is just a blank space until the user clicks some other controls.

**ASPX**

```
 <div class="col-md-12" style="overflow: auto; width: 1150px; max-height: 800px; height: 800px; border-style:solid; border-color: darkblue; border-width:thin;">
   <asp:GridView ID="uxSearchGridView" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" CssClass="GridView"  HeaderStyle-BackColor="#ADD8E6" BorderStyle="Solid" onRowDataBound="uxSearchGridView_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSorting="uxSearchGridView_Sorting" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#D6D2D2" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" SelectedIndex="-1" DataKeyNames="TicketNumber" AllowSorting="True" Font-Size="Small" Width="100%" Visible="True" EnableModelValidation="True" style=" margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
       <Columns>
         <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" SelectText="Details" ButtonType="Button" HeaderText="Select" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="TicketNumber" HeaderText="Ticket Number" SortExpression="Ticket Number" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Complexity" HeaderText="Complexity" SortExpression="Complexity" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="NatureOfInquiry" HeaderText="Nature of Inquiry" SortExpression="NatureOfInquiry" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="SMEResponseDetail" HeaderText="Response" SortExpression="SMEResponseDetail" />
       </Columns> 
       <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
       <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
       <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
       <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
       <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
       <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
       <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
       <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
       <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
   </asp:GridView>
 </div>
```

**C#**

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        _dtMgr = new DataAccessManager()
        string staffName = _dtMgr.GetStaffNameByUser(Session["UserNameSession"].ToString());
        if (staffName == string.Empty)
        {
            //error
        }
        else
        {
            Session["StaffName"] = staffName;
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                uxSearchGridView.DataSource = null;
                uxSearchGridView.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there something I'm leaving out or is there another reason that my headers will not display on page load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally realized that I had to create an empty data table and bind it in order for `ShowHeaderWhenEmpty` to work. On page load, I added null parameters (that allowed null parameters) to my `sp` that would return the `dataset` I would eventually use as the `Datasource` for my `gridview`. This returned an empty table but allowed the headers display. I also added and empty row (just for aesthetic purposes):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  _searchDT = _dtMgr.GetTicketsByKeyword(uxKeywordTextBox.Text, null);
      ....
      if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                DataRow dr = null;
                dr = _searchDT.NewRow();
                _searchDT.Rows.Add();
                uxSearchGridView.DataSource = _searchDT;
                uxSearchGridView.DataBind();
            }
        }
     ...
}
```